# How can I move the delete action to the last column in an ng2 smart table?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2, ng2-smart-table

How can I move the delete action to the last column in an 'ng2' smart table?

I want the only delete action in the last column of my table in my `ng2` smart table. Can someone please assist me with this issue?

The settings and the code of the table I am using is as follows:

```
this.settings = {
                add: {
                    confirmCreate: true,
                    addButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-plus" title="Add"></i>',
                    createButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-save" title="Save"></i>',
                    cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-remove" title="Cancel"></i>'
                },
                delete: {
                    confirmDelete: true,
                    deleteButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-trash" title="Delete"></i>'
                },
                edit: {
                    confirmSave: true,
                    editButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-edit" title="Edit"></i>',
                    saveButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-save" title="Save"></i>',
                    cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-remove" title="Cancel"></i>'
                },
                columns: {
                    logDate: {
                        title: 'Log Date*',
                        filter: false,
                        type: 'custom',
                        width: '5%',
                        renderComponent: DatePickerRenderComponent,
                        editor: {
                            type: 'custom',
                            component: DatePickerEditorComponent,
                        },
                    },
                    category: {
                        filter: false,
                        title: 'Category*',
                        type: 'html',
                        editor: {
                            type: 'list',
                            config: {
                                list: this.customerList,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    partId: {
                        filter: false,
                        title: 'PN/ID#*'
                    },
                    description: {
                        filter: false,
                        title: 'Description'
                    },

                    ws: {
                        filter: false,
                        title: 'WS',
                        type: 'custom',
                        renderComponent: CheckboxRenderComponent,
                        editor: {
                            type: 'custom',
                            component: CheckboxEditorComponent
                        }
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

Use property `actions.position` described on documentation.

> `actions.position`    `'left'|'right'`    Choose actions column position

Example:

```
actions.position: 'right',
add: {
    confirmCreate: true,
    addButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-plus" title="Add"></i>',
    createButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-save" title="Save"></i>',
    cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-remove" title="Cancel"></i>'
},
```

Comment: but this will move all actions to the right side ,but I want only delete to move to the right

Comment: I think this is not possible using smart table due of his limits/proposal.

Comment: can we put a star with red color beside the column titles to show the field as mandatory?